# Node-Red - Catching Error - node-red-contrib-composer

Tags: node-red, hyperledger-composer

I am using composer nodes in nod-red flow
[node-red-contrib-composer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-composer)

There are cases when node is throwing error

> "Error trying invoke business network. Error: Peer has rejected
>   transaction
>   'ce59c38741626ca5dbc1ae7055e0a52297ff99293751f796ed41d40b5cfc59e9'
>   with code MVCC_READ_CONFLICT "

I can see this error in debug console but I cannot catch this error using 
**catch** node available in node-red. I think, in composer nodes, below code is used:

```
    .catch((error) => {
                        node.error(error.message);
     });
```

How can I catch this error in node-red?
I would like to use this error message in order to trigger another flow in same tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the specific details of the error, the reason you cannot handle this error with a Catch node is due to how the composer node is reporting the error.

It is calling `node.error` with a single argument, which means it is logged and no further action taken.

In order to trigger a Catch node, the call to `node.error` must provide a second argument which is the message object the Catch node should send.

I suggest you raise an issue against the composer nodes to get this change made.

Comment: Thank you. How can I do this change locally if possible? If you can suggest me the changes then I will try change and test my node-red.

Comment: As a minimum, you could try changing the `node.error()` call you have shared to be node.error(error.message,{}); - although out of context, I can't say if that makes sense for where that error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned on Rocketchat - the error comes from Fabric - might want to have a watcher that finds the error in the logs (and pulls it into your flow ? ie for the transaction id that failed)  See also here on info about avoiding collisions -> [MVCC_READ_CONFLICT when submitting multiple transactions concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347439/mvcc-read-conflict-when-submitting-multiple-transactions-concurrently)

An error like `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT` can't currently be captured (ie the time of writing) by `debug` node in the node-red flow (only avl in the debug console). Not unless `node.error(msg)` or similar was available in the composer node-red mpdule (eg.  `node.error("Error",msg)`) - so that a `catch` node in node-red may be used to capture that error and go about re-sbumitting a transaction subject to an earlier 'MVCC_READ_CONFLICT'.